# how to store webcam captured image in specified folder and captured image path in mysql database using php..?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to capture image from webcam user image that image stored in specified folder and captured image path store into mysql using php.
I have an problem with webcam captured image path is not stored in mysql database. so please help me...

```js
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
    </script>
<script language="JavaScript">
        webcam.set_api_url( 'test.php' );
      webcam.set_quality( 90 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
      webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
      webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_completion_handler' );

      function take_snapshot(){
       // take snapshot and upload to server
       document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<h1>Uploading...</h1>';
       webcam.snap();
      }

      function my_completion_handler(msg) {
       // extract URL out of PHP output
       if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
        // show JPEG image in page
        document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML ='<h1>Upload Successful!</h1>';
        // reset camera for another shot
        webcam.reset();
       }
       else {alert("PHP Error: " + msg);
       }
      }
     </script>
```

```css
-------------------------------------
____________test.php_________________
    <?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
$name = date('YmdHis');
$newname="images/".$name.".jpg";
$file = file_put_contents( $newname, file_get_contents('php://input') );
if (!$file) {
 print "ERROR: Failed to write data to $filename, check permissions\n";
 exit();
}
else
{
    $sql="Insert into entry(images) values('$newname')";
    $result=mysql_query($con,$sql)
            or die("Error in query");
    $value=mysql_insert_id($con);
    $_SESSION["myvalue"]=$value;
}

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/' . $newname;
print "$url\n";

?>
```

```html
 
   <form>
   <input type=button value="Configure..." onClick="webcam.configure()">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
   </form>
    <div id="upload_results" style="background-color:#eee;"></div>
```

Comment: it should be values('".$newname."')

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? is file uploaded in specific folder?

Comment: @manish shukala when i captured image from web that image stored in specified folder but captured image path is not stored in mysql database.

Comment: Any one please help me..!!!

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that everything works except  the "Insert into entry(images) values('$newname')"?

Try echoing out the full mySQL error instead of the brief "Error in query". It might be the table does not exist, the column does not exist, it has no auto-increment column, another unnamed column has no default... Could be anything.